# WooCommerce get billing & shipping email adress from specific user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Because I want to create my own / custom shipping and billing overview on checkout, I need to fetch all (billing and shipping) user informations from the user account. For most of the data, I can do this with (e.g.):

`$billing_company   = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_company', true );`

For some reasons, I can fetch all usere related informations except the billing and shipping email address. Is there a special function for this or am I missing something?

Thx

Comment: Are these even stored on the user object to begin with? I think they might get stored on the individual orders ...

Comment: I´ve just double checked and it seems like the billing & shipping email is not stored in the user object... This colud mean, that I can´t fetch the email without a initial order?

Comment: Probably not; but a user who never ordered anything, probably then won't have had a chance to enter this information anywhere to begin with either ...?

Comment: The initial shipping and billing informations are served by an external API from our ERP-System so the user does not fill in these informations himself. I proably need to extend the API from the ERP-System so I can get the data again at the checkout page. This will probably be the better solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Or just leave user to fill those first time. Woo will autofill after.